# rails with rmagick and simple test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want just play with  rmagick on rails 4 but get:

```
undefined method `annotate' for #<Array:0xbe4434>
```

controller:

```
class ImgController < ApplicationController
include Magick
def index
  img = Magick::Image.read('public/images/bg.png')
  txt = Draw.new

  img.annotate(txt,  0,0,90,15,  "hello word"){
  txt.gravity = Magick::SouthWestGravity
  txt.pointsize = 30
  txt.fill = '#084B8A'
  txt.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
}
img.write('bg_1.png')
send_data bg_1.to_blob, disposition: 'inline',
type: 'image/png'
end
end
```

gemfile

```
gem 'rmagick',  require: 'RMagick'
```

from irb  rmagick worked fine  with:

```
1. require 'RMagick'
2. include Magick
3.
4. cat = ImageList.new("Cheetah.jpg")
5. cat.display
6. exit
```

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you sure RMagick is installed?

Comment: @RichPeck osx snow leopard

Comment: okay, I have very little experience with RMagick, but on this line - `img.annotate(txt,  0,0,90,15,  "hello word"){` - you're referencing `txt` - perhaps you mean `img`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Magick::Image#read` returns an array of images, because this method may be used for reading animated gifs. Simply call `.first` on the result:

```
img = Magick::Image.read('public/images/bg.png').first
```

Another problem is that you should call annotate on instance of `Draw`, passing `img` as first parameter:

```
Magick::Draw.new.annotate(img, 0, 0, 90, 15, 'hello world') do
  # set options here
  self.gravity = Magick::SouthEastGravity
  # …
end
```

Comment: Argh. You have another problem with your code (while taking `first` is still necessary). Please see update.

Comment: nothing :( doesn't works.  I don't understand because my code works fine on irb and not on rails

Comment: At least the error message **must** have changed. If you show the new error message, I will try to help. My code example came from working project.

Comment: thanks for your help, code works but it is very sloww `Completed 200 OK in 295972ms (Views: 88.9ms)`  big thanks  ;)

Comment: It definitely should not take so long, but it seems to be another issue. Was glad to help.